# Docker daemon can't starting after system reboot

Tags: docker, centos7

I installed Docker according to [this manual](https://docs.docker.com/installation/centos/#install-without-the-script) and triggered the following command:

```
sudo chkconfig docker on
```

Everything works great, but when I reboot the system, Docker daemon is not running.

I also tried this command, but without success.

```
sudo systemctl enable docker
```

My OS is **CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503** and Docker version **1.8.2**

How do I ensure guaranteed start of Docker after a reboot??

Comment: What is the output of `sudo systemctl start docker` and `sudo systemctl status docker`?

Comment: here is the output of `sudo systemctl status docker` after reboot: [goo.gl/21bB2I](http://goo.gl/21bB2I).
When I run `sudo systemctl start docker`, Docker normally works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem.

I had `SocketGroup=docker` configuration in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.socket` file, but at Docker startup time a group **docker** did not exist because I manage my Linux identities (users, groups, etc) with FreeIPA and this starts after Docker.

**Solution**

Add this line to */etc/group* file:

```
docker:x:GID:
```

GID is a same number as is configured in FreeIPA for group **docker**.

Comment: Docker by design does not use any 'external' NSS module and expects only users to exist in /etc/passwd and groups in /etc/group files.

Comment: my hero.... found this 3 days wondering through all the "overflow" sites and endless gitlab issues. and many many re-installations of docker engine. i have installed docker in the past year in many machines (on-prem and aws, windows, linux), this week, 3 machines have this exact same issue. 1 in aws (docker daemon starts fine before) and 2 on-prem machines with no docker installed. very weird.  the os I was troubleshooting was ubuntu 18.04, docker installation step was followed exactly as recommend from the official docker web page.